# Spring - Could not find key 'could not find key 'logging.exception-conversion-word'

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, spring-batch, logback

My Spring-Boot-Batch app is running fine, and it appears all logging is working as expected. I am using Logback and have a logback-spring.xml file that is being read and appears to be setting everything up correctly. However, every time I run the program get the following:

```
13:12:32.538 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'logging.exception-conversion-word' in any property source
13:12:32.553 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'logging.pattern.console' in any property source
13:12:32.553 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'logging.pattern.file' in any property source
13:12:32.553 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'logging.pattern.level' in any property source
2017-05-09 13:12:32,804 1187  DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'logging.register-shutdown-hook' in any property source
```

I do not have said properties in my files, so it is correct in that statement, but what I can not find through Google searching is: What is looking for those properties? Since I do not seem to need said properties, how do I stop it from looking for them? If I need to add them, what are the possible values and how are they being used?

None of my other Spring-Boot-Batch applications have these properties, nor are they throwing this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd simply like them to stop printing, you can add `debug=false` to your application.properties file.

Oddly enough, adding `debug=true` isn't enough to bring them back, either.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems the spring application doesn't get those properties from anywhere.

You can set them in two ways

- Create file with name of `application.properties` and set there the properties,
   **Example :** `logging.pattern.console=example`
- The second way is to send them at runtime when you running your `.jar`,
  **Example :** `java -jar example.jar --logging.pattern.console=example`.

> Read more about properties in `Spring`, [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
>   ,and [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Thanks, but none of my other Spring apps have those properties and none of them throw that message. When I added the property, I still get the message it just changes to "found" instead of "not found." What is causing these to come up in the first place?

Comment: I had a similar issue where it looked for `local.server.port` and all of the upper/lower case and period/underscore permutations thereof causing a large debug dump at the end of a batch run. Simply setting `local.server.port=` in my application.properties file cut down the log junk.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while looking for something else, but in a nutshell - don't worry about them. This is spring-boots autoconfiguration looking for those properties, and if it doesn't find them then there's no harm done.

These are useful properties if you don't want to use your own logback-spring.xml, essentially making it a little simpler to configure. Your logback-spring.xml will override these properties anyway.